# HikariCP getConnection blocks when establishing new connection

Tags: java, multithreading, connection, etl, hikaricp

I am creating an ETL application where I actually need a large number of concurrent connections running long slow queries. It is not uncommon to see the number of concurrent connections to be as large as 100 depending on the machine running the application.

Let's assume it takes about 2s to establish a connection with the database. If I don't use pooling and parallelize connection retrieval with 100 threads then all connection are still established in about 2s. However, while using HikariCP I've noticed that time to establish 100 connections at the start of the application when there is a spike in connection requests, it takes about 200s to establish all connections and often results in timeout.

This drives me to the conclusion that obtaining a new connection is a blocking call. Also it seems that hikariCP pool is lazy initialized and I assume that once it establishes all 100 connections it will try to keep the pool size at 100.

Is there a way to enable more concurrent behaviour of establishing connections in hikariCP? Could I at least force it to concurrently initialize (establish 100 connections) the pool?

One could say that the time to initially establish all connections is irelevant in the lifetime of the application, but I also want to have timeout set to 30seconds which will always result in timeout exception during initial spike demand.

Comment: what are your configurations? as maximumPoolSize? database and hikari version?

Comment: in this example it is maximumPoolSize=100. Database is Oracle and hikariCP version is 3.1.0. Database is not relevant, pool is used with many databases

Comment: did you manage to fix this? i have the same issue